# Creating an intermediate computer server

Tags: networking, webserver

I am staying at a hostel and I can access the Internet in the evening, but not during the day. However, at the computer lab, it's exactly the opposite: I can access the Internet during the day, but not in the evening. The servers for accessing the Internet fot both the computer lab and the hostel are different, but they are both running Windows.

Is it possible that I can set up an intermediary server in the computer lab so that I can use it to access the Internet at the hostel during the day?

Yes, it is legal out here but very few people know about it.

Comment: In what way do the hostel computers prevent you from accessing the Internet during the day? Leaving security and access rights to one side for a while, even if you could do what you were asking you probably wouldn't be able to access the other server anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you are a student. I know that Microsoft offers free copies of Windows Server to its students through the [dreamspark](/questions/tagged/dreamspark) service. What you can do is set up a server that is running a server OS (I'd say 2012 R2, the latest version as of posting) and connect it to the lab network. Assuming that your college network allows access to the local Intranet all the time, you can configure a RemoteApp ([remoteapp](/questions/tagged/remoteapp)) to run Internet Explorer on the server, but display it on your client in the hostel. On the server, create a `.reg` file containing the following contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\TSAppAllowList]
"fDisabledAllowList"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:0
```

and run it on the server. This enables RemoteApp capabilities and allows any app to run remotely.

After that, create a `.rdp` file containing the following contents (replace `[[SERVER-ADDRESS]]` with the computer name or local IP address of the server):

```
screen mode id:i:1
use multimon:i:1
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,2244,149,3044,749
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:1
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:1
allow desktop composition:i:1
disable full window drag:i:0
disable menu anims:i:0
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:[[SERVER_ADDRESS]]
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:1
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
devicestoredirect:s:*
drivestoredirect:s:*

// RemoteApp
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
RemoteApplicationName:s:Internet Explorer
RemoteApplicationProgram:s:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
DisableRemoteAppCheck:i:1
Prompt for Credentials on Client:i:0
Alternate Shell:s:rdpinit.exe
```

and save it on the client. Then, whenever you want to browse the Internet, open this file to launch IE on the server and you're done!

Reference: http://www.daveamenta.com/2012-11/using-remoteapps-on-surface-rt-windows-rt/

Answer (score 4):

Well, whilst you might be able to do this if you had sufficient access to change the configuration of the computer centre's system, it is likely to be considered hacking. Almost certainly against the acceptable use policy and quite possibly illegal.

The configuration has been set that way to keep the systems secure. Unless you have explicit and written consent from the organisation that owns and operates the data centre, don't do it.

Comment: Well, the user does say that it is legal...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using windows to do this would be to set up a linux server with ssh to do this. This could be something as simple as a raspberry pi, or even a VM with bridged networking. You'd just need to be able to install ssh, and have an account on the system.

You'd then be able to make use of ssh tunneling to tunnel traffic, typically through putty as a local proxy. These are the settings I use for putty

[image]

and set your browser or system to use a socks 5 proxy on port 8080